# flot in jquery ui draggable element

Tags: jquery-ui, flot, jquery-ui-draggable

Can anyone help with the following.  Draggable moves the div element, but on stop, only the flot axis labels are moved.  I believe this is because the canvas elements created by flot use absolutely positioned canvas elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Flot Mockup</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <!-- Flot recommends using this for IE < 9 for canvas emulator see https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/README.md -->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- Note: Many extended libraries make use of jQuery.browser which has been deprecated in jquery 1.9 - use 1.8 -->
    <!--<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js" ></script>-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js" ></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js" ></script>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js" ></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" />


    <!-- CUSTOMIZE/OVERRIDE THE DEFAULT CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }


        /* Headers & Footer in Center & East panes */
        h3, h4 { 
            font-size:      1.1em;
            background:     #EEF;
            border:         1px solid #BBB;
            border-width:   0 0 1px;
            padding:        7px 10px;
            margin:         0;
        }



        /* Need this or close button on tab will wrap */
        .ui-tabs-nav li .ui-icon-close { 
            float: left; 
            margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0; 
            cursor: pointer; 
        }



        /*
        *   TAB-THEME ADJUSTMENTS
        */
        .ui-tabs-nav li {
            white-space:    nowrap;
        }
        .ui-tabs-nav li a {
            font-size:      1em !important;
            padding:        4px 1.5ex 3px !important;
        }
        .ui-tabs-panel {
            font-size:      1em !important;
            /* padding:     0 1em !important;*/ 
        }




        #workSpaceTabs{
            padding-bottom: 0 !important;
        }

        .isi-default-plot {
            padding: 20px;
            width: 90%;
            height: 90%;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 14px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Center Layout Panel - Workspace -->
    <div class="ui-layout-center">
    <div id="workSpaceTabs" >

        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel isi-layout-content">
            <div id="t1-sort">
                <div id="t1-c1" class="ui-state-active isi-container" style="width:100%; height:300px">
                    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Drag Me - Flot 1</h3>
                    <div id="t1-c1-p1" class="isi-default-plot isi-flotPlot"></div>
                </div>


                <div id="t1-c2" class="ui-state-active isi-container" style="width:100%; height:250px">
                    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Drag Me - Flot 2</h3>
                    <div id="t1-c2-p2" class="isi-default-plot isi-flotPlot"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="t1-c3" class="ui-state-active isi-container" style="width:100%; height:300px">
                    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Drag Me 3</h3>
                    <p> TODO: Try putting a plot inside me</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>




    <!-- Layout scripting logic -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var tabs = $("#workSpaceTabs").tabs({
            heightStyle:    "fill"

        });

        $("#t1-sort").sortable({
            revert: true
        });

        $(".isi-container").draggable({
            scroll: true
            , connectToSortable: "#t1-sort"
            , containment: "parent" 
            , stop: function( event, ui ) {onContainerDragStop(event, ui);}
        });

    </script>



    <!-- Flot Plotting Logic -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //
        // Global Plots
        //
        var flotPlots = new Array();

        //
        // Std Data Series' from examples
        //
        var d1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
            d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
        }

        var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

        // A null signifies separate line segments
        var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

        //
        // Draw a flot plot in each container
        //
         $(".isi-flotPlot").each(
            function(){

                var thisID = $(this).attr("id");
                var thisSelectorID = "#" + thisID;
                var plot = $.plot(thisSelectorID, [ d1, d2, d3 ]);

                flotPlots.push( {id: thisID, plot: plot} );
            });


    </script>


    <!-- Event Handlers -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //
        // Drag/Sort doesn't move the canvas elements.  
        // Try refreshing them all to work out a fix.
        // 
        function onContainerDragStop(event, ui){

             for(var i = 0 ; i < flotPlots.length; i++){
                //alert("ReDrawing: " + flotPlots[i].id);
                flotPlots[i].plot.resize();
                flotPlots[i].plot.setupGrid();
                flotPlots[i].plot.draw();
             }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Revised -- Here is the generated source before and after the drag operation --

before drag:

```
<div id="t1-c1" class="ui-state-active isi-container ui-draggable" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; position: relative;">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Drag Me - Flot 1</h3>
    <div style="padding: 0px; position: relative;" id="t1-c1-p1" class="isi-default-plot isi-flotPlot"><canvas height="270" width="1634" class="base"></canvas><canvas style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1634px; height: 270px;" height="270" width="1634" class="overlay"></canvas><div class="tickLabels" style="font-size:smaller"><div class="xAxis x1Axis" style="color:#545454"><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:-26px;top:256px;width:108px">0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:93px;top:256px;width:108px">1</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:211px;top:256px;width:108px">2</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:330px;top:256px;width:108px">3</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:449px;top:256px;width:108px">4</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:567px;top:256px;width:108px">5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:686px;top:256px;width:108px">6</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:805px;top:256px;width:108px">7</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:923px;top:256px;width:108px">8</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1042px;top:256px;width:108px">9</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1161px;top:256px;width:108px">10</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1279px;top:256px;width:108px">11</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1398px;top:256px;width:108px">12</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1517px;top:256px;width:108px">13</div></div><div class="yAxis y1Axis" style="color:#545454"><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:242px;right:1613px;width:21px">-2.5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:207px;right:1613px;width:21px">0.0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:172px;right:1613px;width:21px">2.5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:137px;right:1613px;width:21px">5.0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:102px;right:1613px;width:21px">7.5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:67px;right:1613px;width:21px">10.0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:32px;right:1613px;width:21px">12.5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:-3px;right:1613px;width:21px">15.0</div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

after drag:

```
<div class="ui-state-active isi-container ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; position: relative; left: auto; top: auto; display: block;">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Drag Me - Flot 1</h3>
    <div style="padding: 0px; position: relative;" id="t1-c1-p1" class="isi-default-plot isi-flotPlot"><canvas height="270" width="1634" class="base"></canvas><canvas style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1634px; height: 270px;" height="270" width="1634" class="overlay"></canvas><div class="tickLabels" style="font-size:smaller"><div class="xAxis x1Axis" style="color:#545454"><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:-26px;top:256px;width:108px">0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:93px;top:256px;width:108px">1</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:211px;top:256px;width:108px">2</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:330px;top:256px;width:108px">3</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:449px;top:256px;width:108px">4</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:567px;top:256px;width:108px">5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:686px;top:256px;width:108px">6</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:805px;top:256px;width:108px">7</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:923px;top:256px;width:108px">8</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1042px;top:256px;width:108px">9</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1161px;top:256px;width:108px">10</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1279px;top:256px;width:108px">11</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1398px;top:256px;width:108px">12</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:1517px;top:256px;width:108px">13</div></div><div class="yAxis y1Axis" style="color:#545454"><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:242px;right:1613px;width:21px">-2.5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:207px;right:1613px;width:21px">0.0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:172px;right:1613px;width:21px">2.5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:137px;right:1613px;width:21px">5.0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:102px;right:1613px;width:21px">7.5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:67px;right:1613px;width:21px">10.0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:32px;right:1613px;width:21px">12.5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:-3px;right:1613px;width:21px">15.0</div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do the plot container's styles (particularly position) look like after the drag?

Comment: revised to address your question DNS. Note how canvases are generated with absolute positioning.  I could brute force it, but I suspect that will become a nightmare when the plots are "real" with options.  Wondering if there is a way to detach and then reattach, or some other simpler means of accomplising.

Comment: The fact that the canvases use absolute positioning shouldn't matter; their placeholder (isi-default-plot) has positioning, which means that the canvases are positioned with respect to the placeholder, not something else on the page.  Try using the Chrome/Firebug DOM inspector (mouse over to highlight) to confirm that both base and overlay canvases really exist in their pre-drag positions, and whether their parent changes at all during drag.

Comment: The parent doesn't change.  JQueryUI.draggable appears to convert the css relative position to absolute for isi-container elements while dragging.  The inner canvas goes along for the ride, so I would think the (crude) onContainerDragStop function would cause the redraw to occur.  Maybe its a z-indexing problem?

Comment: Its not z-index.  its something related to the flot draw routine.  In, chrome, If I put a break in onContainerDragStop and wait a few seconds content shows up.  Tried to mimic with a setTimeout Function around the plot.draw function with no luck.  plot.resize and plot.setupGrid don't seem to need to be called.

Comment: Are you using Flot master or 0.7?  If 0.7, can you try master and see how that works?

Comment: DNS - Thanks for your assistance working through this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.  Turns out draggable is not required with sortable in my use case.  Seems that usage of draggable and sortable together with a flot element inside gets confounded.  Commenting out the logic as shown in the sample below, solves the problem.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Flot Mockup</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <!-- Flot recommends using this for IE < 9 for canvas emulator see https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/README.md -->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- Note: Many extended libraries make use of jQuery.browser which has been deprecated in jquery 1.9 - use 1.8 -->
    <!--<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js" ></script>-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js" ></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js" ></script>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js" ></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" />


    <!-- CUSTOMIZE/OVERRIDE THE DEFAULT CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }


        /* Headers & Footer in Center & East panes */
        h3, h4 { 
            font-size:      1.1em;
            background:     #EEF;
            border:         1px solid #BBB;
            border-width:   0 0 1px;
            padding:        7px 10px;
            margin:         0;
        }



        /* Need this or close button on tab will wrap */
        .ui-tabs-nav li .ui-icon-close { 
            float: left; 
            margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0; 
            cursor: pointer; 
        }



        /*
        *   TAB-THEME ADJUSTMENTS
        */
        .ui-tabs-nav li {
            white-space:    nowrap;
        }
        .ui-tabs-nav li a {
            font-size:      1em !important;
            padding:        4px 1.5ex 3px !important;
        }
        .ui-tabs-panel {
            font-size:      1em !important;
            /* padding:     0 1em !important;*/ 
        }




        #workSpaceTabs{
            padding-bottom: 0 !important;
        }

        .isi-default-plot {
            padding: 20px;
            width: 90%;
            height: 90%;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 14px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Center Layout Panel - Workspace -->
    <div class="ui-layout-center">
    <div id="workSpaceTabs" >

        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel isi-layout-content">
            <div id="t1-sort">
                <div id="t1-c1" class="ui-state-active isi-container" style="width:100%; height:300px">
                    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Drag Me - Flot 1</h3>
                    <div id="t1-c1-p1" class="isi-default-plot isi-flotPlot"></div>
                </div>


                <div id="t1-c2" class="ui-state-active isi-container" style="width:100%; height:250px">
                    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Drag Me - Flot 2</h3>
                    <div id="t1-c2-p2" class="isi-default-plot isi-flotPlot"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="t1-c3" class="ui-state-active isi-container" style="width:100%; height:300px">
                    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Drag Me 3</h3>
                    <p> TODO: Try putting a plot inside me</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>




    <!-- Layout scripting logic -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var tabs = $("#workSpaceTabs").tabs({
            heightStyle:    "fill"

        });

        $("#t1-sort").sortable({
            revert: true
        });
/*
        $(".isi-container").draggable({
            scroll: true
            , connectToSortable: "#t1-sort"
            , containment: "parent" 
            , stop: function( event, ui ) {onContainerDragStop(event, ui);}
        });
*/
    </script>



    <!-- Flot Plotting Logic -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //
        // Global Plots
        //
        var flotPlots = new Array();

        //
        // Std Data Series' from examples
        //
        var d1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
            d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
        }

        var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

        // A null signifies separate line segments
        var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

        //
        // Draw a flot plot in each container
        //
         $(".isi-flotPlot").each(
            function(){

                var thisID = $(this).attr("id");
                var thisSelectorID = "#" + thisID;
                var plot = $.plot(thisSelectorID, [ d1, d2, d3 ]);

                flotPlots.push( {id: thisID, plot: plot} );
            });


    </script>


    <!-- Event Handlers -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
/*
        //
        // Drag/Sort doesn't move the canvas elements.  
        // Try refreshing them all to work out a fix.
        // 
        function onContainerDragStop(event, ui){

             for(var i = 0 ; i < flotPlots.length; i++){
                //alert("ReDrawing: " + flotPlots[i].id);
                flotPlots[i].plot.resize();
                flotPlots[i].plot.setupGrid();
                flotPlots[i].plot.draw();
             }
        }
*/
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```